# Is WebServices or PageMethods needed anymore with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in Web Forms i used to create WeebServices and PageMethods to be able to call JSON results with jquery, so is this needed anymore with MVC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's what you were using the WebService for, then no, it's not needed anymore.